# How to override CSS in apostrophe-cms pro in TheAposPallete.vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, apostrophe-cms

I'm new to apostrophe-pro and in node_modules I can see a file TheAposPallete.vue which can be located at

> \node_modules@apostrophecms-pro\palette\ui\apos\components

This file has following CSS:

```
  .apos-palette__grouped.is-open .apos-palette__grouped__schema {
      max-height: 100vh;
   }
```

I want to override this since this is causing some issues. I tried overriding this in `index.scss` through `important` flag. But that didn't work.

Is there a way we can override this or is this even overridable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it resolved by overriding the complete path in `index.scss`

```
.apos-palette__grouped.is-open .apos-palette__grouped__schema{
   max-height: 120vh !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add your style in direct in HTML inline CSS and declared it as !important

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).